# Will a Golden Magikarp evolve into a Shiny Gyarados?

Tags: magikarp-jump

In Magikarp Jump, there is a rare chance of catching a Shiny Golden Magikarp.

If a Golden Magikarp evolves, (either by breaking its Everstone or though the Macho Karp event), will it evolve into a Shiny Red Gyarados?

[image: Golden Magikarp]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a shiny Magikarp will evolve into a shiny Gyarados.

[image: Shiny Gyarados]